# Codeigniter- Fatal error: Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, fatal-error

When I try to run a simple function it shows me:

> > A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Site::$model_users
>
> Filename: controllers/site.php
>
> Line Number: 14
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_news() on a non-object in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb130/b418/ipg.blazewarcom/ci/application/controllers/site.php
>   on line 14

**The functions:**

model_users.php located in models folder:

```
public function get_news()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblnews ORDER BY newId DESC LIMIT 3");
    return $query;
}
```

site.php located in controllers folder:

```
public function home_news() {
        $query = $this->model_users->get_news(); //This line causes the problem
        ...
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to call the method `get_news()` on `$this` class?

Try

```
class Site {
   public function home_news() {
        $class_name = new Class_Name();  //change Class_Name() to the class that has the method get_news.
        $query = $class_name->get_news(); //This line caused the problem
        ...
        ...
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to call from site.php to function in model_users.php

Comment: How is the class called that has the method get_news() ? Could you please give some more code showing the class

Comment: So it helped? What was your mistake?

Comment: I just forgot to put this line: $this->load->model("model_users");

Answer (score 0):

**This is how it should be:**

**Model:**

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_news()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblnews ORDER BY newId DESC LIMIT 3");
        return $query;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_users');
    }

    public function home_news() 
    {
        $query = $this->model_users->get_news(); //This line causes the problem
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```